# How to add static transform with right timestamp to rosbag?

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/9106/rosbag-play-tf-static_transform_publisher/) and tried the first answer. My launch file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<launch>
    <param name="use_sim_time"  value="true" />
    <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="davis_camera" args="-0.029793949479807992 -0.00576132479343137 0.11578614371327833 0.20107065010341968 -0.1307783221491868 0.56686050120762888 -0.78812232317925601 davis camera ">
    </node>
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="rosbag_record" args="record -O /home/my_name/PycharmProjects/Project/bag/test.bag -a">
    </node>
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="play"  name="rosbag_play" args="--clock /home/my_name/PycharmProjects/Project/bag/data.bag">
    </node>
</launch>
```

but when I try to use lookuptransform on the bag I get the same error as in the question:

```
tf2.ExtrapolationException: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1535537364.011644125, but only time 0.000000000 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [vicon] to frame [camera]
```

Am I doing something wrong here or why doesn't it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302837/how-to-add-static-transform-with-right-timestamp-to-rosbag?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I was using the tf2_ros package instead of the tf package, changing that and adding a publishing frequency at the end did the trick and I have the transforms with the right timestamps

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0